# Power of unit group $U_r^m$ of $p$-adic number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This question is about a part of the proof of Proposition 6 in Chapter II, §3 from Lang's Algebraic Number Theory.
Let $K$ be a ${\frak p}$-adic field and $U_i = 1+{\frak p}^i$. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer and $m$ a positive integer. For $r$ large enough with $|m\pi^{r+1}|\geq|\pi^{2r}|$ we have for any $x\in{\cal O}_K$:$$(1+x\pi^r)^m\equiv 1+mx\pi^r\pmod {m\pi^{r+1}}$$
From this he deduces that $U_r^m=U_{r+s}$ with $s=\operatorname{ord}_{\frak p} m$. Why is this the case? Clearly from the congruence above we have $U_r^m\subseteq U_{r+s}$.  But why should the reverse inclusion hold?
Maybe one could use Hensel's lemma: Let $1+y\in U_{r+s}$ and write $y=mx\pi^r$ with $x\in {\cal O}_K$. Consider the polynomial $f(t)=(1+t)^m-(1+y)$. If we set $\alpha_0=x\pi^r$ we get by the above: $$f(\alpha_0)\equiv 0\pmod{m\pi^{r+1}}$$
So we can apply Hensel's lemma (Proposition 2) (using $|m\pi^{r+1}|\geq|\pi^{2r}|$) to get a root $\alpha\in{\cal O}_K$ of $f(t)$. Now to conclude $(1+\alpha)^m=1+y\in U_r^m$ we need to show that $\alpha\in{\frak p}^r$, but the estimate in Hensel's lemma only gives us $|\alpha-\alpha_0|\leq\left|\frac{f(\alpha_0)}{f'(\alpha_0)^2}\right|<|\pi|^2$ which is not enough.

Comment: Do you know that group of principal units forms a decreasing filtration? That means for $r>s$  we have $U_r=1+\mathfrak{p}^r  \subseteq 1+\mathfrak{p}^s=U_s$.

Comment: But doesn't that only give us $U_{r+s}\subseteq U_r$? I don't see how this would imply $U_{r+s}\subseteq U_r^m$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the reverse inclusion.

Note that $\pi^r\mathcal{O}_K=\{x \in K~|~ \text{ord}_p(x) \geq r\}$.

Thus, $U_r=1+\pi^r \mathcal{O}_K=1+\{x \in K~|~ \text{ord}_p(x) \geq r\}$.

Now note that $(1+\pi^rx)^m=1+\pi^r \cdot mx \ (\text{mod} \ m \pi^{r+1})$.

More specifically,

\begin{align} 
U_r^m&=1+\{y \in K~|~\text{ord}_p(y=mx)=\text{ord}_p(m)+\text{ord}_p(x) \geq s+r \} \\ &=1+\pi^{r+s}\mathcal{O}_K\\ &=U_{r+s}
\end{align}

Here we have used $s=\text{ord}_p(m)$.

Comment: You didn't check that $U_{r+s}\subset U_r^m$ which is because $U_r^m$ contains some element $(1+\pi^r a)^m \equiv 1+\pi^{r+s} a \bmod a \pi^{r+s+1}$ for each $a\in O_K$ thus it is a dense subgroup of $U_{r+s}$. And since $U_r^m$ is closed we get that $U_r^m=U_{r+s}$.

Comment: @reuns that sounds like a nice approach, but I am not convinced why that congruence implies that $U_r^m$ is dense in $U_{r+s}$: If $1+\pi^{r+s}a\in U_{r+s}$ we need to get arbitrarily good approximations in $U_{r}^m$ for $1+\pi^{r+s}a$ but $(1+\pi^ra)^m$ only gives us one such approximation and if I try to lift that to give an approximation modulo a higher power of $\pi$ I run into the same problem as in the question that we might 'leave' $U_r$, i.e. the approximations just come from $U^m$.

Comment: @Why I am not convinced of the equation $U_r^m=1+\{y \in K~|~\text{ord}_p(y=mx)=\text{ord}_p(m)+\text{ord}_p(x)\}$. That seems like exactly what I am trying to prove

Comment: @asdf321 Which step is unclear to you? Given an element $b\in U_{r+s}$ there is one of $U_r^m$ such that $v(c b-1)\ge v(b-1)+v(\pi)$ so you can approximate $b$ arbitrary well by products of elements of $U_r^m$, ie. the latter is dense. Of course above I meant $(1+\pi^r a)^m \equiv 1+m \pi^r  a \bmod a \pi^{r+s+1}$.

Comment: @reuns Got it! For $b\in U_{r+s}$ there is some $c\in U_r^m$ such that $v(cb-1)\geq v(b-1)+v(\pi)$. Doing the same for $cb$ we get a $d\in U_r^m$ such that $v(dcb-1)\geq v(cb-1)+v(\pi)\geq v(b-1)+2v(\pi)$ and so on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @asdf321, just notice the difference. In case of $U_r$ we are collecting elements $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ whose valuation  $v(x) \geq r$ while in case of $U_r^m$, we are collecting elements $mx$  for the 'above' $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ with $v(mx)=v(m)+v(x) \geq s+ r$. That is, we are multiplying  every elements of the ideal $\mathfrak{p}^r$ (and hence $U_r$) by $m$ to obtain the ideal $\mathfrak{p}^{s+r}$ (and hence $U_{r+s})$.